# Mapping with motion ip

Tags: key-bindings, cursor-movement, cursor-motions

I'm trying to create my own mapping with motion in Vim after reading [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5495/mapping-with-motion) stackexchange question. I'm using the plugin [vimtux](https://github.com/brauner/vimtux) to send code to specific tmux instances and I now want to be able to do this using motion instead of making a detour via visual mode.
What I have so far in my .vimrc:

```
nmap <silent> <leader>c :set opfunc=SendWithMotion<CR>g@
function! SendWithMotion(type)
  silent exec 'normal! `[v`]y`]'
  call SendToTmux(@")
  call ExecuteKeys('Enter')
endfunction
```

This is working great for motions like `\cw` or `\cap`, however if I use `\cip`, the last line of the paragraph is captured only as its first character. E.g.:

```
abcd
abcd
abcd
```

results in sent code:

```
abcd
abcd
a
```

What could be the issue here? Sorry if this has some stupid solution, I'm really new to Vim! But I already love it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, `v` means charwise selection, while you've got the linewise one (`ip`). So you must check the value of `a:type` and build the command in the right way with the help of `:execute` or plain `:if` etc.

Comment: ok, I'll dig into charwise and linewise checking of my argument and if else statements then...

Answer (score 0):

I thought it might be helpful for others if I posted my final solution to my initial problem, although my directly asked question has been answered.
With the help of Matt's obviously correct answer, I changed (copied from existing plugins) my final function to:

```
function! SendWithMotion(type)
  if a:type == 'line'
    let lines = { 'start': line("'["), 'end': line("']") }
    silent exe lines.start . "," . lines.end . "y" 
    silent exe "normal! `]j0"
  else
    silent exe "normal! `[v`]y`]"
  endif
  call SendToTmux(@")
  call ExecuteKeys('Enter')
endfunction
```

which seems, is now behaving as expected.